# fgets() keeps getting skipped before entering loop

Tags: c, string, stdin, fgets

Been trying to remove a character but the call to `fgets` gets skipped/jumped over. On different computers it runs like it should but for some reason, it skips and basically jumps to the end of the program. Any ideas?

Comment: You're mixing line-oriented input `fgets()` with character oriented input.(`getchar()`).     They handle newlines differently, hence interactions like you see, that programmers often don't expect. The solution is to use one input approach or the other, on a given stream, and NEVER mix them   (e.g. use `fgets()` for all input, and extract single characters from the input string if needed).

Comment: what did you mean that it *skips and jumps*? Have you tried to debut it?

Comment: Note: `j--;` does nothing, `j` is reset, `for (j = i; ...` each time the loop is encountered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several problems in your code but I do not see any reason of `fgets()` skipped or jumped over. The `getchar()` function reads the next character from `stdin`. Generally when we give input to the `getchar()` function, we enter the character and press `ENTER` key. This left the `\n` character in input stream which can be consumed by next input function called. But in your case you are not calling any other input function after `getchar()`.
*[Try calling `getchar()` above `fgets()` and give input as - enter a character followed by `ENTER` key. You will see the `fgets()` is skipped because it consumes the leftover `\n` character from input stream `stdin`.]*

**Problem 1:**
Look at this statement:

```
str[j] = str + 1;
```

Since, the `str` is a `char` array, `str[j]` represents a character at location `j` and `str + 1` is pointer. So, this assignment is incompatible because you are trying to assign a `char *` type to a `char`. It should be:

```
str[j] = str[j + 1];
```

**Problem 2:**
Your code is having a logical problem. It is unable to handle the scenario where the character to be removed occurs consecutively in the input string. Test your code for input like "Hello World" *[character `l` is occurring consecutively]*. Your program output will be *[after fixing problem 1]*:

```
Enter a sentence: 
Hello World
This is the sentence: Hello World

Enter character to remove: 
l
Sentence after removal: Helo Word        <==== character l not removed
```

Your program is unable to handle this particular scenario because once it removes a character, in the next iteration it starts with next character.

**Problem 3:**
The `strlen()` return type is `size_t` and you are using `char` type to receive its return value. Instead, you should use `size_t` type.
The `getchar()` return type is `int` *[because it returns the special value `EOF` when the end of the input stream is reached]*. You are using `char` type variable to receive `getchar()` return value.

One more point (it is not a problem but you should be aware of it and take the precautionary measures):
From [**fgets()**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) *[emphasis mine]*:

> Reads at most count - 1 characters from the given file stream and stores them in the character array pointed to by str. **Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character.** If no errors occur, writes a null character at the position immediately after the last character written to str.

So, it is possible that your input buffer passed to `fgets()` can have new line character (`'\n'`) in it. For e.g., if you give input `Hello World` followed by `ENTER` key than the input buffer `str` will have `"Hello World\n"` in it. In your case this will not cause any problem but few extra iteration of loop. You can remove the `\n` from `str` buffer like this:

```
fgets(str, 100, stdin);
str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0; // This will remove the trailing newline character from input buffer
```

Also, you should check the `fgets()` return. In case of failure, `fgets()` returns `NULL`.

Putting these altogether, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    size_t i, j, len;
    int r;

    printf("Enter a sentence: \n");
    if (fgets(str, 100, stdin) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, ("fgets failed"));
        return -1;
    }

    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
    printf("This is the sentence: %s\n", str);

    printf("Enter character to remove: \n");
    r = getchar();

    /*If getchar returns EOF, no need to go through character removal logic*/
    if (r != EOF) {
        len = strlen(str);

        i = 0;
        while (str[i] != '\0') {
            if (str[i] == (char)r) {
                for (j = i; j < len; j++) {
                    str[j] = str[j+1];
                }
                len--;
            }
            else
                i++;
        }
    }

    printf("Sentence after removal: %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
Enter a sentence: 
Hello World
This is the sentence: Hello World
Enter character to remove: 
l
Sentence after removal: Heo Word

# ./a.out
Enter a sentence: 
zzzzz
This is the sentence: zzzzz
Enter character to remove: 
z
Sentence after removal: 

# ./a.out
Enter a sentence: 
aazz
This is the sentence: aazz
Enter character to remove: 
a
Sentence after removal: zz
```

Comment: Extraordinarily good, thorough, instructive response!

Comment: @H.S. is it possible that when I write even more code that consists of fgets() after this that this part is somehow getting messed up by other fgets()

Comment: @SketchupGalaxy No, it will not. Just make sure to read about `fgets()` thoroughly and handle the scenario where the input could be bigger than buffer size passed to `fgets()`. You may need this - [how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `r = getchar();` with `scanf("%c\n", &r);`.

Also, your loop has some bugs or inconsistencies:

1. You're assigning to `str[j]` the value of a pointer. Should be assigning to `str[j]` the value of `str[j+1]`.
2. The end of the inner loop should be `len-1` then.
3. `j--` has no effect at all.
4. You should end your string with `\0` after you're done, otherwise you'll print garbage (in my case it was a bunch of `\n`s).

Putting everything together:

```
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str[i] == r) {
            for (j = i; j < len-1; j++) {
                str[j] = str[j+1];
            }
            len--;
        }
    }
    str[len] = '\0';
    printf("Sentence after removal: %s\n", str);
```

If you want to remove the `\n` at the end of the string after you read it, you can do

```
    str[len] = '\0';
    len--;
```

before the loop.

Comment: `scanf("%c\n", &r);` is a weak suggestion.  Function does not return promptly after entering a `'\n'`, but waits.